# JWT: Why am I always getting token_not_provided?

Tags: jwt, guzzle

I am sending a `PUT` request to an API endpoint I have created. Using jwt, I am able to successfully register and get a token back.

Using Postman, my request(s) work perfectly.

I am using Guzzle within my application to send the `PUT` request. This is what it looks like:

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client('http://foo.mysite.dev/api/');
$uri = 'user/123';
$post_data = array(
    'token' => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGc..., // whole token
    'name' => 'Name',
    'email' => name@email.com,
    'suspended' => 1,
);

$data = json_encode($post_data);

$request = $client->put($uri, array(
    'content-type' => 'application/json'
));

$request->setBody($data);
$response = $request->send();
$json = $response->json();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    error_log('Error: Could not update user:');
    error_log($e->getResponse()->getBody());            
}
```

When I log the `$data` variable to see what it looks like, this is what is returned.

```
error_log(print_r($data, true));

{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL...","name":"Name","email":"name@email.com","suspended":1}

Error: Could not suspend user:
{"error":"token_not_provided"}
```

It seems like all data is getting populated correctly, I am not sure why the system is not finding the token. Running the "same" query through Postman (as a `PUT`) along with the same params works great.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The token should be set in the authorization header, not as a post data parameter

```
$request->addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL...');
```